# Segmentation fault ignored in XCode

Tags: c++, vector, segmentation-fault

I am getting a segmentation fault for this code in a web-based editor, but not in XCode.  I am not that familiar with these errors, but I looked it up and couldn't identify the problem.  One other difference is that I remove the main method when I use the web editor.  Does anyone know what the problem is?  Thanks in advance.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Lexer
{
public: vector <string> tokenize(vector <string> tokens, string input);
};

vector <string> Lexer::tokenize(vector <string> tokens, string input)
{
    vector <string> consumed;

    if(tokens.size()>50)
    {
        tokens.resize(50);
    }

    //The next section sorts the tokens from largest to smallest

    int swap_count = 0; //this tracks whether the sort needs to happen again

    do
    {
        swap_count = 0; // set the swap count to zero

        for(int i=0; i<tokens.size(); i++) //loop that runs the length of the 'tokens' string
        {
            if(tokens[i].length()<tokens[i+1].length()) // if this token is smaller in length than the next token
            {
                tokens[i].swap(tokens[i+1]); //swap the tokens
                swap_count++; //add one to the swap count
            }
        }
    }
    while(swap_count!=0); //while there are swaps

    //The next section consumes the input string.
    while(input.length()>0)
    {
        int count_tokens_consumed=0;

        for(int i=0; i<tokens.size(); i++) // loop set up to go through the units in the tokens vector
        {
            if(tokens[i]==input.substr(0,tokens[i].length())) //if the current token matches the first part of the input
            {
                consumed.push_back(tokens[i]); //add the token to the consumed vector
                input = input.substr(tokens[i].length()); //remove the token from the front of the input string
                count_tokens_consumed++;
                i=int(tokens.size());
            }
        }

        if (count_tokens_consumed==0)
        {
            input = input.substr(1);//or remove the first character on no match
        }
    }

    return consumed;
}

int main()
{
    Lexer LexerOne;
    vector <string> LexerOne_out = LexerOne.tokenize({"AbCd","dEfG","GhIj"},"abCdEfGhIjAbCdEfGhIj");
    for(vector<string>::iterator i = LexerOne_out.begin(); i != LexerOne_out.end(); ++i)

        cout << *i << " ";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The results of undefined behavior are undefined.  (i.e. upon encountering code that invokes undefined behavior, XCode is allowed to crash, or not crash, or steal your stereo, or anything else it chooses to do)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whether the segmentation fault was ignored in one environment, but not another is irrelevant.
The action leading to the segmentation fault is undefined behaviour.

---

The following line of code:

```
line 31: tokens[i+1].length()
```

Is not a valid index into your tokens.
This is because you are iterating from 0 to `tokens.size()`.
The range of valid indexes into tokens would be from 0 to `tokens.size()-1`.

Answer (score 0):

`if(tokens[i].length() < tokens[i+1].length())`

The `i+1` index is out of bounds.

Now to answer as to why you get one behavior when running on one compiler than another, going out of bounds with a vector leads to *undefined behavior*.  Anything can happen, including "work correctly all the time", "work sometimes, crash other times", "crashes all the time", "work on your computer but not another computer", etc.

If you want consistent behavior when you go out of bounds, use `std::vector::at()` instead of `[ ]` when accessing the elements of your vector.

`if(tokens.at(i).length() < tokens.at(i+1).length())`

If you did that, you would have received an `std::out_of_range` exception on both compilers (if the input is the same) instead of a random segmentation fault.

---

If you write code that uses `std::vector`, and you are not using pointers to any great extent, a lot of segmentation fault issues occur due to going out-of-bounds of the vector.  So what I usually recommend is to replace `[ ]` with `at()` to pin down any boundary issues first.  If there are issues, then they get cleaned up first.  Once cleaned up, then the `[ ]` is reintroduced into the code (since `[ ]` does no bounds checking, it will run faster than the same call to `at()`).